# ¿Cómo puedo logearme a una página, pero usando Electron?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Quiero hacer una aplicacion de escritorio para el campus virtual de mi universidad, la quiero hacer en electron, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, envio los datos de logeo al servidor y luego no se que hacer...
Envío los datos de un formulario por POST, tal y como lo hace la pagina web del campus, pero no se que hacer despues???

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado y decir exactamente donde esta el error que tienes. Puedes leer [ask], para modificar tu pregunta y evitar que te la cierren

Comment: Amigo si quieres usar electron el usa las tecnologias web osea que todo lo que haces en una pagina normal lo puedes hacer exactamente en electron incluyendo iframe que puede ser lo que quieres